# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted in sitepress-multilingual-cms

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wpml

I am facing on the error like `PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2097160 bytes)in wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/utilities/class-debug-backtrace.php line 138`.

I tried to increase the memory limit in `wp-config.php` by adding `define("WP_MEMORY_LIMIT", "512M")`, but it didn't help me.

Also, tried to disable `sitepress-multilingual-cms` plugin by renaming the plugin folder name, but it was still no luck.

Is there any way to solve this critical error? If yes, that would be appreciated for any advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress made a core change in version 6.2 that caused an infinite loop in X and Pro. We have fixed the issue in X 10.1.10 and Pro 6.1.10. If possible, please do not update to WordPress 6.2 until you are on these versions. Unfortunately it appears WordPress has changed their default setting to auto update to the latest versions (generally, never a good idea). You can change this in your WordPress settings.

If you are already on WordPress 6.2 and having trouble accessing your site, please remove the X/Pro folder, download the latest version from your Themeco dashboard, and then re-upload and change your theme back to X/Pro. If you wish to manually fix the issue you can add return; to line 194 of framework/legacy/functions/plugins/cornerstone.php.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is indicating that PHP has run out of memory while running the site press-multilingual-cms plugin to the best of my knowledge.

You can try increasing the memory limit for PHP and Here's how you can do it.

Locate the PHP.ini file on your server.

Open the PHP.ini file in a text editor.

Find the following line in the file:

memory_limit = 128M

Increase the value to a higher number, such as 256M or 512M:

memory_limit = 512M

Save the changes to the PHP.ini file.

Restart your web server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) and PHP.

This should increase the amount of memory available for PHP to use and prevent the "Allowed memory size exhausted" error. If the issue persists, you may need to consult with a server administrator or your web host for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have increased memory_limit till 2G, but I am still getting the same issue.